# How can I switch the flag state for locking unlocking the doors?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This script is attached to the doors, There are many doors:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HoriDoorManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public DoorHori door1;
    public DoorHori door2;
    public bool doorLockState;

    void OnTriggerEnter()
    {
        if (doorLockState == false)
        {
            if (door1 != null)
            {
                door1.OpenDoor();
            }

            if (door2 != null)
            {
                door2.OpenDoor();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this script is attached to one empty GameObject:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DoorsLockManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool locked;
    public bool lockStateRealTime = false;
    public Renderer rend;

    private Shader unlitcolor;
    private GameObject[] doorPlanes;

    private void Start()
    {
        doorPlanes = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("DoorPlane");
        ChangeColors(new Color32(255, 0, 0, 255), new Color32(0, 255, 0, 255));
    }

    private void ChangeMaterialSettings()
    {
        unlitcolor = Shader.Find("Unlit/Color");
        rend.material.shader = unlitcolor;
        rend.material.SetFloat("_Metallic", 1);
    }

    private void ChangeColors(Color32 lockedColor, Color32 unlockedColor)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < doorPlanes.Length; i++)
        {
            rend = doorPlanes[i].GetComponent<Renderer>();
            ChangeMaterialSettings();
            if (locked)
            {
                rend.material.color = lockedColor;
            }
            else
            {
                rend.material.color = unlockedColor;
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (lockStateRealTime)
        {
            ChangeColors(new Color32(255, 0, 0, 255), new Color32(0, 255, 0, 255));
            lockStateRealTime = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And last script that make the doors open and close:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class DoorHori : MonoBehaviour {

    public float translateValue;
    public float easeTime;
    public OTween.EaseType ease;
    public float waitTime;

    private Vector3 StartlocalPos;
    private Vector3 endlocalPos;

    private void Start(){
        StartlocalPos = transform.localPosition;    
        gameObject.isStatic = false;
    }

    public void OpenDoor(){
        OTween.ValueTo( gameObject,ease,0.0f,-translateValue,easeTime,0.0f,"StartOpen","UpdateOpenDoor","EndOpen");
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
    }

    private void UpdateOpenDoor(float f){       
        Vector3 pos = transform.TransformDirection( new Vector3( 1,0,0));
        transform.localPosition = StartlocalPos + pos*f;

    }

    private void UpdateCloseDoor(float f){      
        Vector3 pos = transform.TransformDirection( new Vector3( -f,0,0)) ;

        transform.localPosition = endlocalPos-pos;

    }

    private void EndOpen(){
        endlocalPos = transform.localPosition ;
        StartCoroutine( WaitToClose());
    }

    private IEnumerator WaitToClose(){

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        OTween.ValueTo( gameObject,ease,0.0f,translateValue,easeTime,0.0f,"StartClose","UpdateCloseDoor","EndClose");
        GetComponent<AudioSource>().Play();
    }
}
```

When the locked flag is true in the DoorsLockManager script I want to make that the doors will not open in the HoriDoorManager and if the flag is false in DoorsLockManager then open the doors on HoriDoorManager.

Comment: Toggling the locked state is simple: `doorLockState = !doorLockState;`. But there is an issue you will probably need to think about: What do you want your program to do, if you attempt to switch the doorLockedState from "unlocked" to "locked" while some doors are open...

Comment: @elgonzo I forgot to add another script so I updated my question the last script make the doors open/close. Can you show me please how to work with the doorLockState ? So if in the DoorsLockManager it's locked don't open the doors and if in the DoorsLockManager it's unlocked open/close the doors.

Comment: @elgonzo Not sure how to do it but I think that only if someone already entered the trigger area of the door and the door is open even if the state change to locked wait the someone to move out and then close the door. The OnTriggerEnter should complete the operation and then when the door will be closed then the locked state will take effect. At least for now there are no open doors that stay open. They are all open/close..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possible way is to make the DoorsLockManager's locked variable a static variable then Let HoriDoorManager use that for checking via `if(DoorsLockManager.locked)`.

Another way is to convert DoorsLockManager to a Singleton so that the locked variable will remain a class variable.